# Why does Eclipse opens http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/WEB-INF/web.xml

Tags: eclipse, web.xml

I followed the following tutorial (although I installed Glassfish Open Source Edition, instead of Tomcat, and using Eclipse Indigo) : http://www.vogella.de/articles/REST/article.html.

The webservice is ok, but when I "Run" the project from Eclipse, Eclipse opens a new pane showing the result of a Web browsing to http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.jersey.first/WEB-INF/web.xml.
The point is that the browser yields the following result :

```
HTTP Status 404 - 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Status report

message

descriptionThe requested resource () is not available.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1
```

I don't understand what this is. What's the point in getting the web.xml at that point ?
I this a normal behaviour ? How to remove this ?

Thank you !

SCO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i may not be correct but i assume you must have had the focus on web.xml when you clicked run. So eclipse just tried to run whatever you asked it to. Open your index.jspx or whatever jsp page you want to see first and then click run.